# What is the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I want the taylor series expansion around some value $a$ of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. I used the general formula
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) = f(a) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
\end{eqnarray}
But unfortunately, I cannot compute any general formula for $f^{(n)}(a)$. The first derivative is 
$$ f^{(1)}(x)= -\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}.$$The second derivative is 
$$ f^{(2)}(x)= \frac{6x^2-2}{(1+x^2)^3}.$$The third derivative is 
$$ f^{(3)}(x)= \frac{24x(x^2-1)}{(1+x^2)^4}.$$The fourth derivative is 
$$ f^{(4)}(x)= -\frac{24(5x^4-10x^2+12)}{(1+x^2)^5}$$. The fifth derivative is 
$$ f^{(5)}(x)= \frac{240x(3x^4-10x^2+3)}{(1+x^2)^5}$$.

What is the $n$-th derivative of the function for working with the above taylor series which I want to use to prove something?

Comment: your second derivative and your fourth derivative are equal, are you sure that's the case?

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate, Thank you. I correct it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$2f(x)=\frac1{1+ix}+\frac1{1-ix}.$$
Therefore
$$2f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-i)^nn!}{(1+ix)^{n+1}}+\frac{i^nn!}{(1-ix)^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you but I want real values and also around a value $a$.

Comment: That's fine; whenever $x$ is real, then so is $f^{(n)}(x)$. @user85361

Comment: There isn't any convergence requirement like $\vert x\vert <1$?

Comment: @user85361 As you can see, this formula is valid for all real $x$.

Answer (score 5):

Another form of the $n$-th derivative:
$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n n!\frac{\sin((n+1)\cot^{-1} x)}{(1+x^2)^{(n+1)/2}}.$$
It's easy to prove by induction.

Comment: Could we find a tight upper bound for this function or lower bound when the term is negative?

Comment: could you please provide a reference for this excellent equation?

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le k\le n$, the Bell polynomials of the second kind $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})$ satisfy
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
See the papers [2,4] and Section 1.4 in [3] below.
By the Faa di Bruno formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}
\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}f\circ g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(g(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(g'(x),g''(x),\dotsc,g^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr)
\end{equation}
and some properties of the Bell polynomials of the second kind, we find
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac1{1+x^2}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}B_{n,k}(2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}B_{n,k}(2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}2^kB_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}2^k
\frac{(n-k)!}{2^{n-k}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}\\
&=\frac{n!}{(2x)^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k}\frac{(2x)^{2k}}{(1+x^2)^{k+1}}, \quad n\ge0.
\end{align*}

By the method used in the paper [1] below, we can straightforwardly obtain another formula
\begin{equation*}
\biggl(\frac1{1+x^2}\biggr)^{(n)}
=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}
\begin{vmatrix}
2x & 1+x^2 & 0 & \dotsm&0& 0& 0\\
2 & 4x & 1+x^2 & \dotsm& 0&0& 0\\
0 & 6 & 6x & \dotsm& 0& 0&0\\
\dotsm & \dotsm & \dotsm & \ddots&\dotsm& \dotsm& \dotsm\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&2(n-2)x& 1+x^2& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&(n-2)(n-1)&2(n-1)x & 1+x^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm&0& (n-1)n& 2nx
\end{vmatrix},\quad n\ge0.
\end{equation*}

**References**

1. Feng Qi, *Determinantal expressions and recursive relations of Delannoy polynomials and generalized Fibonacci polynomials*, Journal of Nonlinear and Convex Analysis **22** (2021), no. 7, 1225--1239.
2. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterranean Journal of Mathematics **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
4. Feng Qi and Miao-Miao Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.